# django rest auth returns "Password reset e-mail has been sent" when it has not, e.g. because email address not registered

Tags: python, email, django-rest-auth, validationerror

I've set up django-rest-auth to send a password reset email. Unfortunately, the API returns a success message "Password reset e-mail has been sent" even when the mail has actually not been sent, for example because there is no user with that email address.

I'm using Mailgun and can see from the logs that the message was not sent.

Is there any way to get django-rest-auth to return a failure message when the email isn't sent? There is an open issue on the GitHub project for this, so I'm not the only person to have seen this problem.

Edit: I have a partial solution but still can't work out how to return a sensible response from the server instead of creating a server error, see below.

https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/423

I've found the file that generates the response:

venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_auth/views.py

```
class PasswordResetView(GenericAPIView):
    """
    Calls Django Auth PasswordResetForm save method.

    Accepts the following POST parameters: email
    Returns the success/fail message.
    """
    serializer_class = PasswordResetSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Create a serializer with request.data
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        serializer.save()
        # Return the success message with OK HTTP status
        return Response(
            {"detail": _("Password reset e-mail has been sent.")},
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

I think this in turn uses a serializer defined in venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_auth/serializers.py:

```
class PasswordResetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    Serializer for requesting a password reset e-mail.
    """
    email = serializers.EmailField()

    password_reset_form_class = PasswordResetForm

    def get_email_options(self):
        """Override this method to change default e-mail options"""
        return {}

    def validate_email(self, value):
        # Create PasswordResetForm with the serializer
        self.reset_form = self.password_reset_form_class(data=self.initial_data)
        if not self.reset_form.is_valid():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(self.reset_form.errors)

        return value

    def save(self):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        # Set some values to trigger the send_email method.
        opts = {
            'use_https': request.is_secure(),
            'from_email': getattr(settings, 'DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL'),
            'request': request,
        }

        opts.update(self.get_email_options())
        self.reset_form.save(**opts)
```

I found PasswordResetForm referenced in venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py:

```
@csrf_protect
def password_reset(request,
                   template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
                   email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
                   subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
                   password_reset_form=PasswordResetForm,
                   token_generator=default_token_generator,
                   post_reset_redirect=None,
                   from_email=None,
                   extra_context=None,
                   html_email_template_name=None,
                   extra_email_context=None):
    warnings.warn("The password_reset() view is superseded by the "
                  "class-based PasswordResetView().",
                  RemovedInDjango21Warning, stacklevel=2)
    if post_reset_redirect is None:
        post_reset_redirect = reverse('password_reset_done')
    else:
        post_reset_redirect = resolve_url(post_reset_redirect)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = password_reset_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            opts = {
                'use_https': request.is_secure(),
                'token_generator': token_generator,
                'from_email': from_email,
                'email_template_name': email_template_name,
                'subject_template_name': subject_template_name,
                'request': request,
                'html_email_template_name': html_email_template_name,
                'extra_email_context': extra_email_context,
            }
            form.save(**opts)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post_reset_redirect)
    else:
        form = password_reset_form()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': _('Password reset'),
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)

    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context)
```

I'm not very familiar with Python - the whole point of using a framework was to avoid writing standard functions such as auth. But it looks like it's just returning a success message without checking that the email can actually be sent.

Edit: after poking around in the allauth code, I have a partial solution. I've updated the form in forms.py like this:

Modified forms.py:

```
class PasswordResetForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), max_length=254)

    def send_mail(self, subject_template_name, email_template_name,
                  context, from_email, to_email, html_email_template_name=None):
        """
        Send a django.core.mail.EmailMultiAlternatives to `to_email`.
        """
        subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, context)
        # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
        subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
        body = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context)

        email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, from_email, [to_email])
        if html_email_template_name is not None:
            html_email = loader.render_to_string(html_email_template_name, context)
            email_message.attach_alternative(html_email, 'text/html')

        email_message.send()

    def get_users(self, email):
        """Given an email, return matching user(s) who should receive a reset.

        This allows subclasses to more easily customize the default policies
        that prevent inactive users and users with unusable passwords from
        resetting their password.
        """
        active_users = UserModel._default_manager.filter(**{
            '%s__iexact' % UserModel.get_email_field_name(): email,
            'is_active': True,
        })

        if not active_users:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("The e-mail address is not assigned to any user account"),
                code='invalid')
        return (u for u in active_users if u.has_usable_password())

    def save(self, domain_override=None,
             subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
             email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
             use_https=False, token_generator=default_token_generator,
             from_email=None, request=None, html_email_template_name=None,
             extra_email_context=None):
        """
        Generate a one-use only link for resetting password and send it to the
        user.
        """
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        for user in self.get_users(email):
            print('user')
            print(user)
            if not domain_override:
                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                site_name = current_site.name
                domain = current_site.domain
            else:
                site_name = domain = domain_override
            context = {
                'email': email,
                'domain': domain,
                'site_name': site_name,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'user': user,
                'token': token_generator.make_token(user),
                'protocol': 'https' if use_https else 'http',
            }
            if extra_email_context is not None:
                context.update(extra_email_context)
            self.send_mail(
                subject_template_name, email_template_name, context, from_email,
                email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,
            )
```

Note the addition of a check which then raises a forms.ValidationError. The problem with this is that the server then throws an error and returns 500. How can I get it to return a handled error response like 400 with a useful message?

I tried adding a custom clean message but still got a 500 server error:

```
def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        self.users = filter_users_by_email(email)
        if not self.users:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("The e-mail address is not assigned"
                                          " to any user account"))
        return self.cleaned_data["email"]
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: means your not getting emails but it is showing like email has been sent when you do sigin/signup via social login?  is this your problem

Comment: No, the issue is that if a user requests a password reset email for an email address that isn't registered on the system, the API returns a success message even though the email has not been sent. I would like to tell the user the email isn't registered, in case they forgot which email address they used or are not yet registered, but the API doesn't give me that information.

Comment: add this lines in validate_email if not self.reset_form.is_valid():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Error'))

        if not User.objects.filter(email=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Invalid e-mail address'))

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it work. The thing missing is to use DRF's `ValidationError` and not Django's:

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
```

For more details, see my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55083568/2704544).

Comment: i think no need to import ValidationError because it has  inbuilt serializers.ValidationError()

Comment: I just wanted to make clear that the `ValidationError` is not that one of Django